# Pointer initialization (or lack thereof) in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I've programmed in C for a brief moment about 10 years ago, and I've just recently come back to it, or more precisely to C++. So, I apologize in advance if my question is trivial or already posted somewhere I haven't looked yet. Here's the mwe:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    double* a;
    double  b;
    double* c;

    std::cout << "Doing something with a" << std::endl;
    *a = 1;
    std::cout << "Doing something with b" << std::endl;
    b = 2;
    std::cout << "Doing something with c" << std::endl;
    *c = 3;

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I'm trying to understand what happens with this code because I'm puzzled by the behavior of the program. I'm using netbeans, compiling with g++, on windows. This is the result:

```
Doing something with a
Doing something with b
Doing something with c
> Segmentation fault <
```

**What's troubling me is that the operation on a goes through whereas the operation on c crashes.** I would understand that both crash. I would also understand that both pass, though it seems per my research and distant memories I should not be ok with that either. But why does one go through and not the other? The reason I'm wondering is that my program (that was a bit more complicated) was first handling only a. And everything was fine on the surface. Suddenly, I added another variable (c) and the program crashed.

Most importantly, how do I know i'm doing things right in general, based on this example? If the code runs fine with a, what check should I make to know if it actually is proper code? and not just a lucky working example that cannot be generalized?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's because of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), sometimes it might *seem* to work, other times you may develop [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: It is an undefined behaviour. It might crash on the `a` operation as well (and eventually will), if compiled or run on a different machine or in different conditions.

Comment: _`*a = 1;`_ is UB in C++, and as well in C. If you would seriously have used C (even long time ago), you should know that in prior.

Comment: I wonder why the question is downvoted. It is well formed and stands in all of the standards. Well, it is kind of trivial, but still..

Comment: It's not a very bad question

Comment: It's not a bad question, but being more about the programming discipline and procedures than about code, it might belong on Programmers.SE

Comment: @BenVoigt "How does this code work?" questions tend to fit better on SO than on Progs.  The focus of the question appears to be asking about how the implementation details play out.

Comment: @GlenH7: I believe the focus is what is called out by the words "most importantly".

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ As it is written, I only "briefly" studied it. No need to be mean... sorry i asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the code runs fine with a, what check should I make to know if it actually is proper code?

Well, you've just observed that the answer is NOT "testing" (alone).

You need code inspection, either by hand from expert programmers, or automated with the help of "static analysis" tools ([Gimpel PCLint, Coverity, MathWorks Polyspace, KlocWorks, PVS-Studio, Frama, etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B)).

Generally inspection of any critical code will involve both -- once all issues found automatically by static analysis are found, a team of experts will perform a code review.

For non-critical code, often automated analysis (which guarantees to catch certain types of problems, but not all types) plus some testing (which is not guaranteed to catch problems, but often does) is considered to be enough.  Dynamic analysis (such as [Valgrind or Parasoft Insure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis#Examples_of_Tools)), which is stricter than "results look ok", helps tests catch more, but still can't replace inspection.

Any halfway decent static analysis tool will detect that you are reading the value of an uninitialized variable (accessing `*a` must read the address stored in `a`, this is formally called lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and requires that the value has been previously initialized).

---

Something important to note is that while you observed a failure after introducing a second instance of the same bug, **it's also possible for a latent bug to manifest when completely correct changes are made**.  Which of course results in looking at the new code ad absurdum, until one realizes the bug is elsewhere.  In particular, any change to memory layout often affects the behavior of pointer bugs.

Comment: A static analysis tool as crap as _the compiler_ will emit a warning for this. Not sure why the OP didn't see it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Exactly.  A tool that doesn't catch something thi obvious is not worth running... unless it catches some really obscure thing, then you should run it plus the ones that catch the typical bugs.

Comment: I got no warning whatsoever -- I have learned to never ignore warnings. I could copy-paste the build right here, it says there's nothing wrong...

Comment: @Godzy: Which compiler, and are you running with maximum warnings?  (`/W4` for Microsoft C++, `-Wall` for g++ and clang)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, who does my make for me with g++ -- so who knows what goes in the background -- but i've just checked and I indeed have -Wall in my build options.

Comment: @Godzy: Are you looking at the actual compiler output, or an error window which has parsed and filtered the results?  (Hint, if it has sortable columns, it's been parsed)

Comment: @BenVoigt The actual compiler, lots of very long lines with paths everywhere, g++ command lines with -c and -o etc. As I say, I have no idea what neabeans really does but it looks like what I had on linux when typing make by hand in a terminal window. And it usually issues a lot of warnings whenever I do things that i'm not supposed to.

Comment: @Godzy: Interesting, because [For your exact code, g++ shows 3 warnings](http://rextester.com/MDNH75645)

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess I'll forward my questions to netbeans forum then! Maybe it hides things "for your own good" >_<  It may also be the sign I should find another windows IDE...

Comment: @BenVoigt So I started a new project on netbeans (my initial project had a lot commented code unecessary to my question) and just copy pasted from the initial project. Now the warnings show. So... I guess at some point I did something that Netbeans interpreted as deactivating all future warnings? I can't find differences between the two though... Anyway, thanks with your help, man!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comments and answers, as written the variables `a` and `c` likely contain garbage data since you never explicitly initialize them - whatever was in the memory locations that these stack variables are assigned to. When you subsequently do `*a = 1` and `*c = 3` you are writing `1` and `3` to arbitrary locations in memory. This might or might not cause a segfault - you were just lucky the first time. Thus "undefined behavior".

Comment: Or unlucky, that a real bug exists and the testing didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

> I would understand that both crash

That is the problem. Both *can* crash, but expect anything to happen, including not-a-crash.

Answer (score -1):

> but why does one go through

It didn't go through. It put that value to the random location in heap of your process.

Comment: @BenVoigt ... or memory of of your computer. Depends on architecture of processor, OS and how they map process addresses to physical memory. Is this OK now ?